# How to resize image from S3 with Sharp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sharp

I am trying to resize the uploaded image from S3 using @aws-sdk/v3 in Node.js API.

First, I get the object (image) from S3 as shown here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascriptv3/example_code/s3/src/s3_getobject.ts

```js
...

  const params = { Bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME, Key: key }
  const data = await s3.send(new GetObjectCommand(params))
  console.log(` >> Success, bucket returned:`, data) // Log correctly
```

Then I try to resize the data (image):

```js
  const convert = sharp(data).resize(size, size).webp()
```

But it throws:

```
 >> data.type: object
(node:35583) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Input file is missing
...
```

And I am not sure how should I upload it back?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think the `sharp` constructor accepts a buffer, but what you're passing it is the entire response from the SDK request. Instead, try passing data.Body to sharp fn like this:

`const convert = sharp(data.Body).resize(size, size).webp();`

Answer (score 1):

`data.Body` is of type Readable ([a readable stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/getobjectcommandoutput.html#body))

You can use a stream directly with sharp ([see stream example on sharp readme](https://github.com/lovell/sharp#stream))

In your case this gives:

```js
  const params = { Bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME, Key: key }
  const data = await s3.send(new GetObjectCommand(params))

  const converter = await sharp().resize(size, size).webp()
  const resizedBody = (data.Body as Readable).pipe(converter);
```